# Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof. while I delete firebase user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase and android studio. and I have a problem that is occured while I trying delete user. What is only one way to access My Application is phonenumber authentication.

I already know about that when I delete user, must have to reauthentication.
So I refered to firebase docs and tried them. AuthCredential.getCredential() method requires several values although I have only PhoneNumber and UID.
that is all I know

This is the code

```
AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider
                        .getCredential(user.getUid(), null);

                user.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                    //재인증 성공시
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        //삭제
                        user.delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("result", "User account deleted.");
                                }else{
                                    Log.d("", task.getException().getStackTrace().toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

And This is the Exceptions
:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, ortemprary proof.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
        at com.dataflow.deliverytalk.Activities.popup.LogoutPopupActivity$1$override.onClick(LogoutPopupActivity.java:58)
        at com.dataflow.deliverytalk.Activities.popup.LogoutPopupActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(LogoutPopupActivity.java)
        at com.dataflow.deliverytalk.Activities.popup.LogoutPopupActivity$1.onClick(LogoutPopupActivity.java)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can also delete user using cloud function without having to re-authenticate user and by just providing the uid. Here's how

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.body.uid === undefined) {
    res.status(400).send('No user id defined');
  } else {
    var userId = req.body.uid;

    admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Successfully deleted user");    
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error deleting user: ", error);
        });

    res.status(200).end();
}
});
```

More [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I have an another problem... Can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016643/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-error-on-android-studio-retrofit2

Answer (score 0):

just discover that the

```
 <TextInput value={code} onChangeText={text => setCode(text)} />
```

code above uses text input value to code and from the mobile, you need to over the textinput and enter the generated code from your firebase test mobile code