# Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 Error on Android Studio using Retrofit2

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem that "Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0".

What I wanna do is FirebaseUser delete using CloudFunction on Firebase.

There is no return but the Error says that "there is unexpected json token #"

This is some codes:

- CloudFunctionsService( Interface )

```
public interface CloudFunctionsService {

    @POST("deleteUser")
    Call<Void> deleteUser(@Body String uid);
}
```

- FunctionRetrofit ( RetrofitClass )

```
public class FunctionRetrofit {
    private static FunctionRetrofit instance = new FunctionRetrofit();

    public static FunctionRetrofit getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    private CloudFunctionsService cfs = retrofit.create(CloudFunctionsService.class);
    public CloudFunctionsService getService(){
        return cfs;
    }

}
```

- function deleteUser ( on FirebaseCloudFunction )

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.body.uid === undefined) {
      res.status(400).send('No user id defined');
    } else {
      var userId = req.body.uid;

      admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
          .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully deleted user");    
          })
          .catch(error=> {
              console.log("Error deleting user: ", error);
          });

      res.status(200).end();
    } 
  });
```

- Code Executing ( Activity )
  result is success but actually not changed anything

```
Call<Void> res = FunctionRetrofit.getInstance().getService().deleteUser(user.getUid());
                res.enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                        Log.d("success", "suceess");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Error", t.getMessage().toLowerCase());
                    }
                });
```

- Error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the json you are sending?

Comment: I wouldn't send any json but only String value. that is Firebase UID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>As you are using the `GsonConverterFactory`, I think it's expecting json (or to serialize to JSON) when you use the `@Body` annotation. As you are passing a raw String value I think this is where it errors.</s>

Please disregard the answer above. The GsonConverterFactory will serialise your own Type to JSON, however you are sending in a raw String value. This will not be serialized so the body of the post for an id of 3 will be "3" - I think the api you are calling for deleteUser is expecting JSON in the body which you are not sending which is why you are getting the error. I would check the docs of the Firebase API call you are making to see what format it expects the post body to be in. It is more likely to be something like:

```
{
    "userId": "3"
}
```

If this is the case then you would need a class like:

```
public class User {
    private String userId;

    public User(String userId){
        this.userId  = userId;
    }
}
```

You are currently sending a " character as the first character when it's probably expecting a { to signify starting a JSON object

Comment: Then what can I some modify?
I have to send POST with a parameter that key(required).

Comment: I tried to change @Body to @Query("uid") but it is still not work

Comment: The @Query("uid") will attempt to send the id as a query parameter which is probably not what you want

Comment: @Jin-gukPark was the comment and updated answer any help?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for my Application. have a nice day!